# java string.Substring StringIndexOutOfBoundsException inside loop

Tags: java, android

Can someone explain fallowing? Here is code sample: Function is called with parameter: "S26V5"

```
private String uniqueCode(String inp) 
{
  String index = "023456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  int basse = index.length();
  String outt = "";
  inp = new StringBuilder(inp).reverse().toString();
  double oout = 0;
  int lenn = inp.length() - 1;
  Log.d("nom", "String inp lenght:" + Integer.toString(lenn));
    for (int i = 0; i <= lenn; i++)
    {
        double pow = Math.pow(basse, lenn - 1);
        Log.d("nom", "i=" + Integer.toString(i));
        Log.d("nom1",inp.substring(i, 1));
        Log.d("nom2", Integer.toString(index.lastIndexOf(inp.substring(i, 1))));
        oout += index.lastIndexOf(inp.substring(i, 1)) * pow;
    }
  outt = Double.toString(oout); //oout.ToString("F2");
  outt = outt.substring(0, outt.lastIndexOf('.'));
  outt = outt.substring(3);
  return outt;
}
```

Here is log from logcat:

```
nom(2597): String inp lenght:4 <- Ok, string lenght
nom(2597): i=0 <- first iteration
nom1(2597): 5 <- inp.substring(i, 1) first time
nom2(2597): 4 <- index.lastIndexOf(.... first time
nom(2597): i=1 <- second iteration and 
nom2(2597): 34 <- next is index.lastIndexOf(....
nom(2597): i=2
AndroidRuntime(2597): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(2597): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
E/AndroidRuntime(2597): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(2597): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; regionStart=2; regionLength=-1
E/AndroidRuntime(2597):     at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
E/AndroidRuntime(2597):     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
E/AndroidRuntime(2597):     at Bar.Man.BarManActivity.uniqueCode(BarManActivity.java:750)
```

And question is: why in second iteration not printed `inp.substring(i, 1)` ?
And i am constantly getting `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

> IndexOutOfBoundsException -
>
> if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex
>   is larger than the length of this String object, **or beginIndex is
>   larger than endIndex**.

You'll fail in `inp.substring(i, 1)` when `i > 1`.

Comment: I tried to convert my C# code. Now i see difference. In C# it is: `public string Substring(int startIndex, int length)`. Is that function in java?

Comment: @Guntis substring in Java is `substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)`

Comment: @MarounMaroun, i already figured that out. Java does not have that function ? I just need to do that: inp.substring\(i, **i+**1\) ?