# get java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException Error when try to binary to text convertion

Tags: java, string, binary

I am new to java.

i want to create program to convert binary stream to text in java.in my program first i can give the number of binary streams as input and then i can give binary numbers.as output i want to get texts corresponding to binary numbers.but i get error in my program.below i mentioned error and program.thank you.

- Error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
    at javaapplication32.JavaApplication32.main(JavaApplication32.java:23)`

23rd line is `int m = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(8*k,(k+1)*8),2);`

- code:

  ```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class JavaApplication32 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO code application logic here
  String s="";
  int j;
  Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);

  int b=a.nextInt();
  String arr[]=new String[b];

  for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
      arr[i]=a.next();

  }
  for(j=0;j<b;j++){
      for(int k=0;k<arr[j].length()/8;k++){
          int m = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(8*k,(k+1)*8),2);
          s += (char)(m);
      }
      System.out.println(s);
      s="";
          }
       }

  }
  ```
- Example:

`input:`

`2
011100000111100101110100011010000110111101101110
0110110001110101011011`

`output:`

`python
lu`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java string.Substring StringIndexOutOfBoundsException inside loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910791/java-string-substring-stringindexoutofboundsexception-inside-loop)

Comment: Try to explain in your own words how your code should work. Condition in your loop is based on `arr[j]` but you are "cutting" parts from `s` which also should store your result.

Comment: @Tom i tried my best.i am new to programming.i cant understand this.but thank for your effort.

Comment: @Pshemo you will get idea about my program when u see my example.i am new to programming.help me to solve this.

Comment: Let me rephrase my advice. Imagine you are explaining your program to someone else (this is called [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)). This way you can notice things you want to do, but see that some part of your code doesn't actually follow what you want. For now best advice I can give you is to rename your variables using full names to describe their purpose. For instance instead of `s` use `resultString`. This will allow you to see that your code is doing `resultString.substring(8*k,(k+1)*8)`, but do you really want to pick new data from *result*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this line :

```java
String s="";
```

You initialize your string `s` with a 0-length string, and you use it in your loop without assigning it :

```java
for(int k=0;k<arr[j].length()/8;k++){
    int m = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(8*k,(k+1)*8),2); // It crashes here because 's' still have a length of 0, and you ask the substring method to get the substring between indexes 0 and 8
    s += (char)(m);
}
```

What i think you wanted to do is more like this :

```java
for(int k=0;k<arr[j].length()/8;k++){
    int m = Integer.parseInt(arr[j].substring(8*k,(k+1)*8),2); // here, with arr[j], you use your input
    s += (char)(m);
}
```

And with this input :

```java
2
011100000111100101110100011010000110111101101110
0110110001110101011011
```

It outputs this :

```java
python
lu
```